# jquery ui :window resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Please look at the format of my code:
In the below example,
I try to Applying resizable window but without success.
Many thanks,

jquery ui code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#simpleResize" ).resizable({ minHeight: 50, minWidth: 50, maxHeight: 400, maxWidth: 400});
});
```

[link for code example](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/hcGpQ/34/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the markup - you don't have to / shouldn't supply the elements for drag handles, setting the `ui-*` classes, etc. Resizable does all that by itself. [I forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FAzzw/) so you can see how it works.